# 13:21:59,854 ERROR HibernateUtil:42 - Error initializing database

Tags: xml, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and I am trying to run a junit test case, but getting the following Exception:

```
13:21:59,854 ERROR HibernateUtil:42 - Error initializing database
13:21:59,853 ERROR ErrorLogger:57 - Error parsing XML (1) : XML version  "2.0" is not supported, only XML 1.0 is supported.
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Could you help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**"XML version "2.0" is not supported, only XML 1.0 is supported"**

Looks like one of your configuration xml is using `version="2.0"` instead of `version="1.0"` in the `xml prolog`.

Can you check the `hibernate.cfg.xml` and mapping files(hbm) if present.